# How to remove large white blocks from Excel preview in Google Drive?

Tags: microsoft-excel, libreoffice-calc, google-drive, preview, visual-artifacts

Does anyone know how to remove these large white blocks from the preview of an Excel file in Google Drive?  The file itself is somewhat old and has gone through many large changes, including conversion to Libre Calc and back to Excel.  My guess is that these blocks are artifacts for something that got introduced along the way that Excel itself is able to handle gracefully.  Opening the file for editing in Google Sheets also handles the presumed artifacts gracefully, so that they do not appear.  Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like shapes or textboxes hovering in front of the cells.

Do they not appear at all when opening in either excel or google sheets? Is it just in the preview? How do you actually preview the file in google sheets?

If you save the old file from .xls to .xlsx then preview, does it not then fix it?

Otherwise, perhaps import fully into Sheets, and export again to .xlsx from Sheets.

Comment: The boxes do not appear when the file is viewed in Excel or Google Sheets, but they only appear when the file is viewed in the Google Drive preview.  I open the preview by double-clicking the .xlsx file.  I'd prefer to avoid translating the file between file formats, as I think that's how this mess got started.  A surgical fix is much preferred.

Comment: "Translating" the file may be the only way to remove these spurious shapes from your file. It is probably a hidden shape/object. Converting between formats might just remove them. This video might help, as a surgical approach: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-h3XTtY4wwg&t=149s